# Linear transform from $_2F_1(a,b;c;\frac1x)$ to $_2F_1(\alpha,\beta;\gamma;\frac{1-x}{2})$?

Tags: calculus, special-functions, linear-transformations, hypergeometric-function, integral-transforms

For $x>1$, is there a linear transform which transforms $\frac1x$ to $\frac{1-x}{2}$ for the hypergeometric function $_2F_1$, i.e., $_2F_1(a,b;c;\frac1x)$ in terms of $_2F_1(\alpha,\beta;\gamma;\frac{1-x}{2})$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless we put some restrictions on parameters $a$, $b$, $c$, the argument of the hypergeometric function $_2F_1(a,b;c;x)$ can only transform between six cross-ratios
$$x,\quad 1-x,\quad \frac1x,\quad \frac{x}{x-1}, \quad \frac{1}{1-x},\quad \frac{x-1}{x},$$
hence the answer to your question : there isn't.